# 'Limit selection to visible' suddenly not working in user perspective?

Tags: vertices

So I'm working on my model, same as normal and go to select "Limit selection to visible" which makes all the vertices visible and select-able. Except they're not. 
[image]
I've taken a screenshot and you can actually see the "button" for it is highlighted like it's on but isn't working.

I had a look around and saw someone make a similar post except theirs is for the Ortho view, not the user perspective. Is this a glitch or some sort of setting I need to fix?

Update: I also notice the further I scroll away from the model, I can see the back vertices as if it were activated.
[image]

I opened a new project to see if this was an issue with the program itself or to do with the setting in blender. It works normally with the new project but in this current project(that are shown in the screenshots below) the limit selection to visible doesn't work. Based on this I am pretty sure it's something to do with the settings.

While I appreciate temporary fixes, I really need to know how to properly fix this issue so I can get it to work normally again.

Update:

This is how it normally works for me, I open the program and it looks like this before I press the button and after:

[image]

Now when I try to "disable" it by pressing that same button(exactly same as I always have done) nothing happens and only becomes partially visible,like in the screenshots of the issue above this.

**So telling me I just need to "disable" it (when I've explained that I *literally* cannot do that for whatever is causing the issue) is not helping at all.**

Comment: Where's the option for that? To my knowledge I haven't done anything that could have caused this effect and even when I try enabling/disabling it still doesn't work either way :/

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking at it the wrong way...it is "limiting the selection to visible" (the verts up front) right now. It sounds like you want to *disable* it. Also you might want to fix your normals (Select All > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>).

Let me clarify:

- When the button is *disabled* you can "see through" it
- When the button is *enabled* it appears opaque

Comment: Thanks but I really need to know how to get it working again since it's vital for the current model I'm working on and my normals are just fine, I double checked to be sure. I really don't want to come across as rude but I just need to know how to fix this asap :(

Comment: It sounds like the problem is with the clipping settings in the properties panel and the scale of your model. What you said in the edit to your question sounds normal - there are some strange things that start happening when you zoom in this far. If you just need to select those verts, try switching to wireframe view or hiding the faces in front of them (Select Faces > H)

Comment: I didn't even think to switch to wireframe mode, thank you! :D Also, what's the default setting for the clipping distance minimum? I changed it because it wouldn't let me get very close before part of the model vanishes but I'll try setting it to default to see if that fixes the problem P:

Comment: The default is 0.1. Please accept my answer.

Comment: But your answer doesn't solve the main issue of how to fix the problem with the limit selection not working as it used to(even though you've given me a temporary fix) I still need to know how to properly fix this issue. I opened a new project to see if it was the program or not and it works just fine, so it has something to do with the settings.

Comment: Alright, I looked at the new screenshots you posted...you have this *enabled*. You need to *disable* it. Sure when you zoom out the verts that are close behind faces will start showing through (this is a "problem" in most 3D programs). Notice how the large parts of the head **never** are see through.

Comment: And to disable it, you just click on it, basically turning the button on/off enables and disables it. I'm adding new screenshots to show how it usually works up until this problem.